# Творення української термінології механізмами вторинної номінації. Історія та сьогодення

Tags: терміни, неологізми, морфологія

Які організовані процеси по створенню національної термінології механізмами вторинної номінації мали місце для Української мови? Коли вони були? Хто їх проводив? Які їх результати? Які з подібних процесів відбуваються зараз?

Мова іде про створення власної національної термінології для іншомовних термінів (неологізмів), які входили в широкий вжиток з нішевих дисциплін.

Прикладами результатів таких процесів є:

- "стіжок" (як термін, що використовувався років 100 тому) для зараз вживаного математичного терміну "конус".
- влучне "реп'яшок" для англійського терміну "cookie" зі сфери IT.
- польське "czujnik" для англійського "sensor".
- польське "koszykówka" для англійського "basketball".

Які є подібні ініціативи в іншомовних середовищах? Які яскраві приклади є? Чи існує систематизований досвід, який варто переймати?

Comment: А ви зможете пояснити, чому "реп'яшок" влучне для перекладу "cookie"? І до чого тут "magic cookies"?

Comment: Cookie використовуються в IT для того, щоб сервер "закидав" на комп'ютер користувача якусь інформацію. Після того, як комп'ютер дістав такий cookie, він при кожному звертанні до того сервера повідомляє ці cookie знову і знову. Тобто Ваш комп'ютер дістає свій "запах", який легко впізнає сервер.

"Реп'яшок" - це теж щось таке, що "прилипає" до одягу якщо пройдеш коло нього, і тоді здалека видно, де ви були, і що ви "помічені" таким реп'яшком. Тобто якщо б звичайному житті я б хотів вас відрізнити від двійника, то я б міг вам в спину кинути реп'яшка, і потім би вас впізнавав по ньому.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko а чому ви питаєтеся про "magic cookies"?

Comment: Добре, уточню запитання. У печива є передісторія. Чому назвали печиво? Яка передісторія у реп'яшка щодо комп'ютера? Чому вирішили розірвати цю історію за допомогою слова реп'ях? Яке право мали розривати цей зв'язок ті, хто вигадав подібне використання? Чому не можна було перекласти як печіво?

Answer (score 18):

Таке явище відоме як [*мовний/лінґвістичний пуризм/протекціонізм*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC). Слово «пуризм» походить від латинського *purus* «чистий» (пор. англ. *pure*). Найвідомішими його прикладами є:

- чеський пуризм ХІХ століття, коли з чеської практично всі запозичення було видалено й замінено словами, що утворені з чеських морфем, наприклад такі інтернаціоналізми, як «театр» та «музика» було замінено відповідно на «divadlo» (від *dívat se*, «дивитися») та «hudba» (від *hučet*, «гучати, гудіти»).
- [ісландський пуризм](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_purism_in_Icelandic) ­– рух за очищення ісландської від запозичень та повернення її до середньовічних стандартів, почався в ХІХ ст. й триває досі, це основа мовної політики в Ісландії. Як наслідок, в сучасній ісландській мові практично немає слів, які хоча б якось були схожі на англіцизми чи інтернаціоналізми, наприклад «метеоролоґія» ісландською – це *veðurfræði* (*veður* «погода» + *fræði* «наука»), «музика» – *tónlist* (*tón* «звук» + *list* «мистецтво»).
- [турецький революційний пуризм](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_vocabulary#Origins) – коли в 1923 році постала Турецька Республіка, її уряд на чолі з Мустафою Кемалем Ататюрком взяв курс на переведення країни на европейські стандарти, було введено европейський одяг, алфавіт турецької було змінено з арабо-перського на латинку, та найбільш за все було змінено саму турецьку мову: тисячі запозичень з арабської та перської було усунено й замінено або на новоутворені слова з турецьких морфем або на архаїчні турецькі слова. Ця зміна була така докорінна, що сучасним туркам треба в університеті вивчати турецьку мову часів Османської імперії, аби розуміти турецькі тексти, написані до 1923 року. Однак, всі арабські та перські слова вилучити не вдалося, їх і зараз досить багато в турецькій, але все ж на порядки менше, ніж було до реформи.

Типи пуризму [перераховано тут](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_purism) (англ.), а ще є таке явище, як [мовне планування](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F), та нам до такого планування ще далеко.

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю, як щодо руху (може, є якісь таємні секти пуристів, щось на кшталт "Варваризми на гілляку" чи "Калькотворців на ножі"), але процес використання наявного в мові слова на позначення іншомовних термінів зветься вторинною номінацією (як от польські *piłka nożna* і *koszykówka*), якщо Ви це мали на увазі, звісно.

Answer (score 1):

Пан [Павло Штепа](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%A8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0) намагався повернути вживані чи розробити на основі українського словотвору через [Словник чужомовних слів і термінів](//archive.org/stream/shtepa1977) 1977.

Наприклад щодо панових прикладів там:

> Баскетбол — кошиківка
>   Конус — стіжок
>   Сенсор *відсутний, але*
>   Сенсоріюм (мед.) — почуття, чуйність, свідомість
>   Сенсорний — змисловий, чуттєвий

---

Також доповню [відповідь](/a/364/585) пана [Yellow Sky](/users/66/yellow-sky) україномовними статтями про:

- [Ісляндський мовний пуризм](//r2u.org.ua/node/45)
- [Ататюркова реформа турецької мови](//r2u.org.ua/node/48)
- [Пуризм у термінології: український досвід на європейському тлі](https://uamodna.com/articles/puryzm-u-terminologiyi-ukrayinsjkyy-dosvid-na-evropeysjkomu-tli/)